# Javascript: jQuery : Declare dynamic variables with numeric prefixes from Json

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, var

I have a json back with jquery

I would like to do this:

```
var $item1 = $('<div class="gallery-item item1">');
var $item2 = $('<div class="gallery-item item2">');
....
var $items = $item1.add($item2).add($item3)....;
```

I try to do like that, but I can not make a dynamic variable

```
   if(response){
       var items = [];
       $.each( response, function( key, val ) {
        // console.log('id :',key);
        // console.log('val :',val);
          var $item+key= $(val);
       });
       // var $items = $item1.add($item2).add($item3)....;
      }
```

Comment: what actually are you asking for?? @pablofrR

Comment: Edit you question and make it more helpful for future visitors; with better title and explanation about your intention; so that we could upvote if deemed

Comment: I want to create multiple VAR from JSON, to add them like this var $ items = $ item1.add ($ item2) .add ($ item3) ....;

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpraKY

Comment: you want to put all the object stored in `$item1`, `$item2` and so on in an array?? or you want to add the elements selected using `selectors` from JSON to the list??

Comment: oh I got you; you want to dynamically declare variables with prefixes you get as `key`

Comment: yes it is, and finaly push on big var  var $items = $item1.add($item2).add($item3)....;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What $.add() do is simply add the selected elements to selection. What you intended may be different but what I understood from your post is you wanted to select all the new divs created according to the JSON available.

For that purpose you can do:

```js
var response = {
  "$item1": '<div class="gallery-item item1">',
  "$item2": '<div class="gallery-item item2">',
  "$item3": '<div class="gallery-item item3">'
};
if (response) {
  var $items;
  $.each(response, function(key, val) {
    eval(key + "=$('" + val + "')");
    var e = eval(key);
    $items = ($items== null)?e:$items.add(e);
  
    /* for visual output */
    e.html(key);
    $("body").append(e);
    /* for visual output */
  });
}
```

```css
.gallery-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.item1 {
  background: red;
}
.item2 {
  background: green;
}
.item3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also keep in mind, you should avoid using eval() as much as possible. Question yourself if you really needed to do such things? It could have been achieved with simply selecting with:

```
var $items = $(".gallery-item");
```

Comment: I do not know the number of item.

How to do this:

 var $items = $item1.add($item2).add($item3);

This does not work : 
 var $items;
  $.each(response, function(key, val) {
    eval(key + "=$('" + val + "')");
    var $items = key.add(key);
  });

Comment: @pablofr it seems that you are accessing $item1 from outside the scope of local variable. If you want it outside, then declare the variable as global.

Comment: I agree, but how? I dont know the number of this item in my json response before parse processing.

Comment: @pablofr I have made few changes in above answer. It should accept multiple divs now. I am using cell, so its having some difficulties answering.

Comment: My goal is to load a jQuery object.

Is a complete example:

http://37.187.62.99/

click "Load from js" =>  ok, but "Load from Json" => dont work

I use json to have object.

Comment: I have checked your work and found a solution. Change: eval( key + "=$('" + val + "')"); into: var temp=$.parseHTML(val); eval(key + "= temp");

Comment: If you think your question is answered, then please tick the answer as correct. It will inspire answerer to help more.